# Porquê brasileiro e não brasilês ou brasiliano?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, gentílicos

O sufixo *eiro* é extremamente comum na língua portuguesa, servindo para formar desde nome de plantas, como tomateiro, até adjetivos abstratos, como prazenteiro (da antiga palavra prazente, agradável). Mas entre todos os países do planeta, o Brasil é o único cujo adjetivo nacional é formado com este sufixo. Por que razão foi usado o sufixo **eiro** e não um dos sufixos comuns em gentílicos como **ês, ano, iano**, ou mesmo **ão** (*francês, mexicano, alemão*)?

English summary: The word *Brasileiro*, Portuguese for *Brazilian*, is uniquely formed among all Portuguese national adjectives. Why is that?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Mas se te chocar, tens sinónimos: brasiliano, brasiliense, brasilense, brasílico... :)

Comment: Tens razão. Mas raramente usados.

Comment: Talvez tenha alguma relação com a época do Brasil colônia; há outros gentílicos que são formados com _-eiro_, como "mineiro", "campineiro", etc.

Comment: Deve ter. O gentílico com certeza já era _brasileiro_ antes da independência. Campineiro é de Campinas, SP, certo?

Comment: @Jacinto correto!

Comment: obs: não usamos a palavra brasiliense como sinônimo de brasileiro, embora possa constar em dicionários.  "Brasiliense", para nós, é aquele que é natural ou habitante da cidade de Brasília

Comment: @Jacinto  Acabei de aprender que aquele que nasce em Campinas é "campineiro".  Sempre achei que fosse "campinense".

Comment: Não é o local apropriado para perguntar mas...qual o adjetivo para aquele que nasceu em Viana do Castelo e Póvoa do Varzim.

Comment: O primeiro nome que me veio à cabeça foi _poveiro_, que ao que parece está mais associado aos pescadores, mas também existe [_povoense_](http://poveiro61.blogspot.pt/2009/07/poveiro-ou-povoense.html), e também encontrei _varzinense_.

Comment: Um natural de Viana do Castelo é _vianense_ ou _vianês_, mas um _vianense_ também pode ser de Viana do Alentejo.

Comment: @Jacinto Valeu !   (acredito que "valeu" seja uma gíria exclusivamente brasileira. = "obrigado")

Comment: Ora essa! Sim, não creio que se use _valeu_ por cá, mas estou par. Também não sei se se usa _ora essa_ no Brasil neste contexto.

Comment: Acho que o correto seria: BRASILÊS (do Brasil)
BRASILIANO (de Brasília)

Comment: @Hebert Marques - Devíamos realizar um novo acordo ortográfico e alterar isso. Mesmo sabendo que essa discrepância seria quase impossível de retirar do tratamento e utilização popular. Pois, por igual a discriminação, seja ela qual seja, vejo uma ligeira e incomoda, em saber que somos tratados de forma diferente.

Comment: Luis F Veríssimo publicou em 2 de 95, em sua coluna do Jornal do Brasil, uma crônica em que comentava uma carta que recebera de uma leitora demonstrando estranhamento quanto ao funcionamento do sufixo -eiro. Para a leitora, era estranho que brasileiro fosse o único adjetivo pátrio terminado em -eiro. Veríssimo diz que “existem suecos, ingleses e brasileiros, como existem médicos, terapeutas e curandeiros” e completa ainda que “as profissões de lixeiro e coveiro e carcereiro podem ser respeitáveis, mas o eiro é sinal de que elas não têm status. É a diferença entre jornalista e jornaleiro”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several theories on the etymology of "brasileiro".  Most linguists believe the demonym was first used to refer to those merchants who carried "pau-brazil" from Brazil to Europe. About two centuries later it came to be used to refer to anyone born in Brazil.

Muitas são as versões a cerca da origem do gentílico "brasileiro".  A mais aceita diz que inicialmente a palavra referia-se àquele que vinha do Brasil para a Europa com o objetivo de comercializar o pau-brasil. E faz sentido, uma vez que usamos o sufixo -eiro para designar profissões: açougueiro, sapateiro, ferreiro, banqueiro, tintureiro, barbeiro, cabeleireiro, etc.

> Os habitantes naturais do Brasil são denominados brasileiros, cujo gentílico é registrado em português a partir de 1706 que se referia inicialmente apenas aos que comercializavam pau-brasil. Entretanto, foi apenas em 1824, na primeira constituição brasileira, que o gentílico "brasileiro" passou legalmente a designar as pessoas naturais do Brasil. Há ainda a possibilidade do uso de outros gentílicos como brasiliano, brasílico, brasílio e brasiliense (esse último também atribuído aos habitantes de Brasília) para designar os naturais do Brasil. [**from Wikipedia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimologia_de_Brasil)

Comment: O que me surpreende é que o primeiro registo não seja mas antigo. A extração do pau-brasil foi a primeira coisa a que os portugueses se dedicaram no Brasil, mas foi logo logo suplantada pelo negócio do açúcar logo que a colonização começou a sério, em meados de quinhentos,

Comment: O sufixo *eiro* também é utilizado para derivar profissões que trabalham com a palavra raiz, como, por exemplo, *mineiro*, *garimpeiro* e *cozinheiro* (quem trabalha em *mina*, no *garimpo* e na *cozinha*), *ferreiro*, *livreiro* e *cabeleireiro* (quem trabalha com *ferro*, com *livro* e com *cabeleira*), *cavaleiro* (quem monta *cavalo*), *seringueiro* (quem extrai latex de *seringueira*) entre outros e inclusive o próprio *brasileiro* (quem antigamente extraia e processava pau-*brasil*).  Por assim dizer, nós brasileiros já tínhamos profissão antes mesmo de termos nacionalidade.  =D

Comment: @MarceloVentura e os brasileiros mineiros já nascem com dupla jornada. Há também os [penicheiros (Portugal)](http://www.cm-peniche.pt/News/newsdetail.aspx?news=b523d449-b2f9-4027-97d8-b1806fafcc6f), [burreiros (Castela)](https://www.escapadarural.com/que-hacer/trefacio) e [rosaleiros (Galiza)](http://portal.concellodorosal.es/). Gentílicos derivados de profissões ou atividades, com "-eiro", são comuns a nível municipal, mas a nível nacional acho que só há brasileiro.